# Python Fix colorbar in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get rid of the overlap of the images and colorbar values on the right side, but nothing seems to work. I have tried the 'tight' command and to shrink the size of the color bar text. The former does not help and the latter does not seem to work at all. (Is this possible?) I need a way to read these numbers, it does not really matter how. (As long as they don't overlap)

[image]

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=gs[0])
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2, subplot_spec=gs[1])

fig = plt.figure()


ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0, 0])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg1),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0, 1])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg2),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0, 2])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg3),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1, 0])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg4),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1, 1])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg5),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1, 2])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg6),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2, 1])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg7),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2, 2])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg8),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[2, 0])
plt.imshow(getpoly(seg9),origin="lower")
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])



ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 0])
plt.imshow(h1,origin="lower")
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0, 1])
plt.imshow(h2,origin="lower")
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1, 0])
plt.imshow(getpoly(h2),origin="lower")
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)  
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1, 1])
plt.imshow(h1-getpoly(h2),origin="lower")
plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: is this the full code or part of it?

Comment: you can consider using pcolormesh instead of imshow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look at the [colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#colorbar-whose-height-or-width-in-sync-with-the-master-axes)-example.

The idea is to cut a bit of the axes using `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable` and create a new axes into which the colorbar can be placed, using `fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2)
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(3, 3, subplot_spec=gs[0])
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2, subplot_spec=gs[1])

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(9):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[i//3, i%3])
    ax.imshow(np.random.rand(4,4))
    ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])


for i in range(4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs1[i//2, i%2])
    im = ax.imshow(np.random.rand(4,4))
    ax.set_xticks([]); ax.set_yticks([])
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, cax=cax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found it easier to [add the colorbar separately](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html)

```
    cax = fig.add_axes([0.125, 0.925, 0.775, 0.0725])   
    #the numbers in fig.add_axes are all percentages
    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=low_val, vmax=high_val)
    mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap='rainbow', norm=norm, orientation='horizontal')
```

[fig.add_axes details](https://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=fig%20add_axes#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)

Comment: I don't think there is any reason not to use the image for colorbar creation.  The problem here is related to positioning the colorbar. So the question is rather, how would you find good coordinates to place the `cax`?